# How to generate an index with xmlmind docbook editor?

Tags: xml, indexing, docbook

I am new to xml, but not to latex. I started using xmlmind.
I have a simple docbook example where I have only a term *`test`* indexed.
The pdf or html generated does not include the index. What I am missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book version="5.1" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xila="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude/local-attributes"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:trans="http://docbook.org/ns/transclusion"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
<info>
<title/>
<author>
  <personname><firstname/><surname/></personname>

  <affiliation>
    <orgname/>
  </affiliation>
</author>

<pubdate/>
</info>

<chapter>
<title/>
<section>
  <title/>
  <para>test<indexterm class="singular">
      <primary>test</primary>
    </indexterm></para>
</section>
</chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: Isn’t xmlmind just an editor? It’s not the tool you’re using to actually generate the HTML and PDF output is it? Regardless, please consider using https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45078427/edit to edit/update your question to explicitly state exactly what tool or xmlmind feature/function you’re using to create the HTML and PDF output.

Comment: obviously not: you may generate an html or a pdf document using it. But I not experienced enough so see all the implications and turn the screws to use it fully. However, the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an

```
<index/>
```

after the

```
</chapter>
```

term.

Comment: Even though this answer is rather thin (it does not explain WHY it works; see http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/GenerateIndex.html), you should mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved the problem.